# How to set application name when creating .deb, using Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly, packaging

When I open created .deb package , my application name is UNKNOWN . Please help, how to fix it...

Comment: Is it in the control file, http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/How-to-make-deb-packages/ I've never done it before, there is a section on it there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill in and uncomment the `description` and `long_description` in the [setup.py file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~grabovsky-pavel/8.6-biblio/quickly_trunk/view/head:/setup.py#L94) before you run any Quickly packaging command. This is where Quickly gets the short and long descriptions for your app shown in the Ubuntu Software Centre.